# Correct way of redirecting view on AJAX 'success' in MVC app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Question background:**

I've implemented a search feature in the header of my MVC site. Its features a input text-box with a 'Search' Button.

**The Issue:**

Currently I have implemented a AJAX function in the shared master layout.cshtml view that handles the click event of the search button, as shown:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".searchBtn").click(function () {

        var $searchTerm = $("#searchInput").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ProductSearch", "Product")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                "searchTerm": $searchTerm,
                "pageNumber": 0
            },
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = result.url;
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the `ProductSearch` method of the the `Product` Controller the AJAX call. The search term along with the page number is sent to the controller method:

```
public ActionResult ProductSearch(string searchTerm, int pageNumber)
{
    if (searchId == 0)
    {
        searchId = 1;
    }

    var productDetailHandler = new ProductPageDBHandler(
        new ProductDetailSqlServerHandler(new ProductDetailDataSetConvertor()));

    var searchList = productDetailHandler.ProductSearch(searchTerm);

    return View(searchList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 3));
}
```

The problem is that this seems to **not** be returning the view I've associated with the `ProductSearch` method. How do I go about correctly redirecting to thw correct view once the user has submitted their search query?

Comment: Why would you do an ajax post and then redirect (you may as well just do a standard submit and redirect in the controller). The value of `result` in your success function is the view you returned in the `ProductSearch` method, so all you want is to update the DOM - e.g. `success: function (result) { $('#someElement').html(result); }`

Comment: Yup, totally agree with @StephenMuecke. Can you please explain the logic behind the redirection here?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Many thanks for your answer. I'm pretty new to MVC and learning it through trial and error. Your answer was perfect though and has given me exactly what I need. I have created a div that encapsulates my RenderBody in the master layout that appends the html result to this based on the div ID. Works perfectly. Please set your comment as the answer and I'll select it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax function is calling a method that returns a view. Change you `success` callback to

```
success: function (result) {
  $('#someElement').html(result);
},
```

This will replace the contents of `<div id="someElement"></div>` with the returned view.